# Is there a plugin with a widget to enter XML text instead of of org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In one of my E4 RCP based application (namely JMSToolBox) I would like to replace a standard "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text" input field by a widget to allow users to enter XML text in a more friendly way. 
At a minimumm the widget needs to have some basic color features and if possible have an auto "tag closing"

After googling for hours it seems that such "editor" is included with WST but I was not able to find such a widget

Q:

- Does such widget exist (SWT or JFace) ? It must be easily be included
  in a RCP app (ie withoud dragging tens of dependencies)
- If so, what plugin should I declare in the dependency list of my app and what is the name/class of such a widget and is there an
  associated documentation to use it.

I am conscious that I could develop my own widget (based on the StyleText widget)
but I would prefer reusing an existing one if possible

(The application is 100% E4 without the compatibility framework)

Comment: javafx may be an option. It also can be [added](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/10/adding-javafx-to-your-eclipse-project/) to eclipse.

Comment: The JFace `org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer` class can be used as the basis of such a widget, but it requires quite a lot of code to set it up for XML. This is what the 'Preferences > Ant > Editor > Formatter' preference page code uses.

Comment: @svasa tx for your answer but I'll not go that way

Comment: @greg-449 this is interesting, I'll investigate this path and try to find some nice implementations of such a widget if it exists.  I'm wondering, the "plugin.xml" (source editor only..) in eclipse RCP is exactly what I'm looking for...Does someone know what the class that implements this widget? Maybe I need to extends some extension point?thx

Comment: The plugin.xml editor is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.plugin.ManifestEditor`. This is a very complex editor.